# Turning String textfile into object array

Tags: java, arrays, string, text-files

I want to use a textfile and take each line and put it into an classobject array. This is my code

```
try {
    // Open the file that is the first
    // command line parameter
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("Patient.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
    String strLine;
    // Read file line by line
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // Print the content on the console
        System.out.println (strLine);
    }
    // Close the input stream
    in.close();
} catch (Exception e) { // Catch exception if any
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

I need to transform this into an array object and this is how i want it to look like

```
Patient1 p[] = new Patient1[5];
p[0] = 001, "John", 17, 100, 65, 110, 110, 110, 109, 111, 114, 113, "Swaying, Nausea";
p[1] = 002, "Sun Min", 18, 101, 70, 113, 113, 110, 119, 111, 114, 113, "None";
```

and so on.

Comment: And I want a pony. Seriously though, you need to tell us what you've tried and then ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of what AVD had suggested, you can accomplish what you want with a constructor that took in your values - although it's not suggested to use too many parameters in a constructor (for readability and debugging's sake).  Depending on the way your data is ordered and read, you could even use [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to get everything into one type (i.e. String).

```
public class Patient {

   public Patient(String name, String id, String symptoms, String measurements) {  to get the individual fields from using a delimiter.

        // Stuff to fill in the fields goes here
    }
}
```

You would invoke this by using the call `new Patient("John, "001", "Swaying, Nausea", ...)`.  Again, this depends on how you read the data coming in; if you cannot bunch the data up in a reasonable way, then you could also opt to create [accessors and mutators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method).

Comment: public Patient1(int i,String n, int a, double w, int h,int bp1, int bp2, int bp3, int bp4, int bp5, int bp6, int bp7, String s){

                  
          id = i; <br/>
          name = n;<br/>
          age = a;<br/>
          weight = w;<br/>
          height = h;<br/>
          BP1 = bp1;<br/>
          BP2 = bp2;<br/>
          BP3 = bp3;<br/>
          BP4 = bp4;<br/>
          BP5 = bp5;<br/>
          BP6 = bp6;<br/>
          BP7 = bp7;<br/>
          SYM = s;<br/>
       What do I do now?

Comment: Can I identify each line by an array number?

Comment: @user1181810, you could edit your question to include what you've tried so far; it'll be far easier to read.  As for identifying each line by an array number, I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by this.  If you store each `Patient` object into an array or `ArrayList`, you'll be able to get them back in the order that they came in.  (You can extend `toString()` and return the values of each object if you want.)  If you're still unsure, update your question to clarify your intent.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Patient class with 13 fields, constructors and setter/getter.

```
public class Patient
{
   private String field1;
   private String field2; 
   private int field3;
   ....
   public void setField1(String field1) { this.field1=field1; }
   public String getField1() { return field1;}
   ...   
}
```

and use `ArrayList<Patient>` instead of array.

```
ArrayList<Patient> patients=new ArrayList<Patient>();
Patient pat=new Patient();
//set value to the patient object
patients.add(pat);
```

Comment: I have 13 methods like getID() and getName() how can I connect the string with the right method?